# Bazel Dockerfile stucks in CI/CD

Tags: docker, dockerfile, bazel

I am using Dockerfile that uses bazel. I am able to run it locally fine but on jenkins the following step stucks forever.

```
RUN mkdir /ibazel && cd /ibazel &&    git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-watcher.git && cd bazel-watcher &&    bazelisk build --remote_cache=grpcs://zZFyJEcPqL96jYEw2I6Y@cloud.buildbuddy.io //ibazel
 ---> Running in d15597cf056a
```

I am getting

```
Cannot contact worker-b51c7740-c71b-4cc6-b540-bb8a02e2f9d2-6x3db-rqvc7: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@b2d0fa7:JNLP4-connect connection from ip-10-104-80-225.ec2.internal/10.104.80.225:52356": Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from ip-10-104-80-225.ec2.internal/10.104.80.225:52356 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
```

Comment: It's look like there is connection issue,maybe firewall.

Comment: What can be the possible solutions, pardon i am not a devops guy

Comment: The error look like the Jenkins master can't connect to the agent for some reson.
It's could be that there is a firewall blocking the connection or maybe the agent is down on the agent machine.